# How to import qgis into a jupyter notebook when using a conda environment?

Tags: pyqgis, jupyter-notebook

System: Windows 10

conda version : 23.3.1

I have setup a conda environment with qgis according to this: https://gisunchained.wordpress.com/2019/05/29/using-qgis-from-conda/

However, I used the newest version of python (which is now in 2023 python 3.11) and the stable qgis version  3.28.5.

So:

```
C:\Users\iik> conda create –name with_qgis python=3.11
C:\Users\iik> conda activate with_qgis
(with_qgis) C:\Users\iik> conda install qgis=3.28.5 --channel conda-forge
```

Then I added the kernel to jupyter notebook

```
(with_qgis) C:\Users\iik> conda install ipykernel
(with_qgis) C:\Users\iik> python -m ipykernel install --user --name with_qgis
```

Generally I'm then able to open jupyter notebook, select the relevant kernel and use the installed libraries. But importing qgis like this in jupyter:

```
import qgis
```

Just gives the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qgis'
```

IMPORTANT!!!
If I activate the conda environment in the terminal, activate python and then import qgis, I get no error at all, but all seems to work fine.

```
(with_qgis) C:\Users\iik> python
>>>import qgis
>>>
```

So I assume, the library is correctly installed, but jupyter notebook cannot find the library?

What do I need to do to be able to import qgis into the jupyter notebook?

Comment: Activate the conda environment in the terminal, then start jupyter from that terminal.

Comment: For this approach I would need to install jupyter into that conda environment. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I think I found an interesting discussion on this import error, when using jupyter notebooks and conda environments, which may help to understand the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58068818/how-to-use-jupyter-notebooks-in-a-conda-environment

Answer (score 4):

The solution to use qgis in a conda environment within a jupyter notebook is to install qgis as well as jupyter notebook into the conda environment, and then activate jupyter notebook from inside the conda environment, so:

```
C:\Users\iik> conda create –name with_qgis_jptr python=3.11
C:\Users\iik> conda activate with_qgis_jptr
(with_qgis_jptr) C:\Users\iik> conda install jupyter
(with_qgis_jptr) C:\Users\iik> conda install qgis=3.28.5 --channel conda-forge
(with_qgis_jptr) C:\Users\iik> jupyter notebook
```

This opens the jupyter notebook browser, where you then create a new jupyter notebook using the 'ipykernel' in the jupyter menu and import qgis into the notebook:

```
import qgis
```